# How to check if extension/add-on used in Mozilla Firefox is a new tab extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I can't find out how to check if the extension used in Mozilla Firefox is a new tab extension.

It works for Google Chrome. I am using the following code in my Google Chrome extension while using `webextension-polyfill` to be cross-platform compatible

```
import browser from 'webextension-polyfill'

const results = await browser.management.getAll()
  extensions = results.filter(extension =>
    extension.permissions.includes('newTabPageOverride'),
  )
```

This does not work in Firefox as it does not have a special type like `newTabPageOverride` in `permissions` array

How can I find out which extension is a New Tab Extension in Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: `newTabPageOverride` is a non-documented internal hack in Chrome, which is probably why it wasn't implemented in Firefox. You can file a feature request on https://bugzil.la, if it's not already submitted.

Comment: @wOxxOm so is there no way to do it in Firefox?

Comment: I also filed a feature request on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1533765)

Comment: So I guess it isn't gonna happen as they closed the issue & would re-open it someday in the future